# get error code of script ran within bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script (script A) which runs a secondary bash script (script B).

```
sh scriptB.sh
exitStatus = ?
```

I need to get the exit code of the script B when I run it inside script A.

How can I do?

Comment: $? test this value. It contains the exit status of the previous command.

Comment: ah ok thanks I thought it wouldn't work inside a script :/ so silly

Comment: Should I post it as an answer ? What's the proper custom to do at SO ? (I am new here =] )

Comment: ^^ Yes, please post that as answer...

Comment: You also cannot have spaces on each side of the equal sign with variable assignments in bash.  It should be: `exitStatus="$?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [3.4.2 Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) of the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

> The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may
>   only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> ?
>
> ($?) Expands to the exit status of the most recently executedforeground pipeline.